# Can integer division be rounded up, instead of down?

Tags: ruby, integer-division

Is there a way to round the result of integer division *up* to the nearest integer, rather than *down*?

For example, I would like to change the default behavior:

```
irb(main):001:0> 5 / 2
=> 2
```

To the following behavior:

```
irb(main):001:0> 5 / 2
=> 3
```

Answer (score 3):

This is rather an algorithm question than a ruby specific question.
Try `(a + b - 1) / b`. For example

```
(5 + 2 - 1) / 2  #=> 3
(10 + 3 - 1) / 3  #=> 4
(6 + 3 - 1) / 3  #=> 2
```

You can define an instance method, say `divide_by`, in the `Integer` class (monkey patch):

```
class Integer
  def divide_by(divisor)
    (self + divisor - 1) / divisor
  end
end
```

According to my benchmark result, it's about 1/2 times faster than the `to_f` then `ceil` solution.

**CORRECTION**

The method shown above gives wrong result when both the dividend and the divisor are negative.

Here's the method that gives the correct result in all cases: `(a * 2 + b) / (b * 2)`

```
a = 5
b = 2
(a * 2 + b) / (b * 2)  #=> 3

a = 6
b = 2
(a * 2 + b) / (b * 2)  #=> 3

a = 5
b = 1
(a * 2 + b) / (b * 2)  #=> 5

a = -5
b = 2
(a * 2 + b) / (b * 2)  #=> -2 (-2.5 rounded up to -2)

a = 5
b = -2
(a * 2 + b) / (b * 2)  #=> -2 (-2.5 rounded up to -2)

a = -5
b = -2
(a * 2 + b) / (b * 2)  #=> 3

a = 10
b = 0
(a * 2 + b) / (b * 2)  #=> raises ZeroDivisionError
```

The monkey patch should be

```
class Integer
  def divide_by(divisor)
    (self * 2 + divisor) / (divisor * 2)
  end
end
```

Mathematical Proof:

The dividend `a` and the divisor `b` meets the equation `a = kb + m` where `a`, `b`, `k`, `m` are all integers, `b` is not zero, and m is between `b` and 0 (can be 0).

For example, when `a` is 5 and `b` is 2, then `a = 2b + 1`, thus in this case, `k = 2` and `m = 1`.

Another example for negative divisor, `a` is 5, `b` is -2, then `a = -3b + (-1)`, thus `k = -3` and `m = -1`.

```
(2a + b) / 2b
= (2(kb + m) + b) / 2b
= (2kb + b + 2m) / 2b
```

When `m = 0`

```
(2kb + b + 2m) / 2b
= (2k + 1)b / 2b
= k + (1 / 2)
= k + 0  # in Ruby
= k  # in Ruby
```

and since `k = a / b`, we got the correct answer.

When `m` is not 0,

```
(2kb + b + 2m) / 2b
= ((2k + 2)b - b + 2m) / 2b
= (k + 1) + (2m - b) / 2b
```

If `b > 0`, then `2m - b < b` so `(2m - b) / 2b < 1 / 2`. So the second term is always 0 in integer division.

If `b < 0`, then `2m - b > b` and still `(2m - b) / 2b < 1 / 2` so the second term is still 0.

In either case, `(2a + b) / 2b` is rounded to `k + 1` when `m` is not 0.

Comment: Just add the divisor to the dividend, and subtract by 1, then divide the result by the divisor.

Comment: That's a very interesting algorithm. Is there a proof that it works for all cases?

Comment: @Toby1Kenobi Sadly this method fails to deliver the expected result when both `a` and `b` are negative. I'm working on a solution now.

Comment: Awesome! If I were designing a programming language then it would definitely feature a rounded up intended division, with this formula behind it.

Answer (score 2):

The function you are looking for is `ceil`.

Ceil returns the nearest integer, rounded upwards, for a floating point number.

```
4/3 = 1
4.0/3.0 = 1.3333...3
(4.0/3.0).ceil = 2
```

Also, note that this rounds in the positive direction, so

```
(-4.0/3.0).ceil = -1, NOT -2
```

- Also, there is the corresponding `floor` function which rounds downwards.

Comment: You can also write `4.fdiv(3).ceil`

Comment: This will fail for certain inputs due to floating point inaccuracy. Aetherus's answer will not. There's probably a better example, but I tried 34524123126231231213535212/34524123126231231213535211. Your answer returns 1 due to the floating point format truncating the least significant digits. Aetherus's correctly returns 2.

Comment: What you mean is that, for integers `x` and `y`, to divide `x` by `y`, rounding up, you can write `(x.to_f/y).ceil`, but that's what you say. You only refer to floating-point division. The second way has nothing to do with floats. It's simply `-(-x/y)`. The last sentence is irrelevant and, considering that you have given two ways, and there are others, the first is out-of-place.  While writing this, I see someone downvoted, probably for the poor exposition.

Comment: @Max, that's a valid point, but not necessarily a weakness of the methods, depending on the application. The methods may be perfectly fine if not calculating distances to far-away galaxies. A proviso is called for in the answer, however.

Comment: I finally got around to computing the limit: 17952053266956643 is the largest integer that works with this method (though that might be implementation-dependent) in the sense that `x.to_f/(x-1).to_f` is not exactly `1.0`

Answer (score 0):

If what you actually want is to Integer div and round up if there's any left over, just do it straightforward as the logic would dictate on paper using a second line of modular operation (%) to check the remainders of the division:

```
a = 5
b = 2

result = a  / b #=> 2
result += 1 if (a % b).positive?

#=> 3

a = 6
b = 3
result = a  / b #=> 2
result += 1 if (a % b).positive?

#=> 2
```